# pip install ffiplatform.VerificationError OpenSSL

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, openssl, pip

I want to install some python libraries with the pip programm, but it always ends up with the same error. I'm using Windows 8.1 and have python 2.7 installed with python(x,y). Once I reinstalled the whole python and python(x,y), but it doesn't helped.

I think it has to do something with the OpenSSL, but I don't know what to do :(

Here is the error log (it doesn't matter what I want to install):

```
$ pip install graphviz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.7-xy.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2672, in load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2345, in load
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2351, in resolve
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 51, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 4, in <module>
    binding = Binding()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 113, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    libraries=libraries,
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\utils.py", line 80, in build_ffi
    extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 340, in verify
    lib = self.verifier.load_library()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 75, in load_library
    return self._load_library()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 151, in _load_library
    return self._vengine.load_library()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\vengine_cpy.py", line 149, in load_library
    raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\
\cryptography\\_Cryptography_cffi_36a40ff0x2bad1bae.pyd': DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The file "_Cryptography_cffi_36a40ff0x2bad1bae.pyd" is exactly there...

Comment: Maybe this is a related problem, but I don't really understand how can I do this on Windows without a working pip...

http://chriskief.com/2014/03/25/installing-cryptography-via-pip-with-macports-or-homebrew/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).